# If $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \left| a_{nk}\right|^2 < M$ for any $n$, show that $\left| \sum_{k=1}^\infty (a_{nk}-b_k)\right| \rightarrow 0 $

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

> For each $n$, let $a_n=(a_{nk})_k$ be a sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ such that
> $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \left| a_{nk}\right|^2 < M,$$
> for any $n$. Let $b=(b_k)_k$ is a sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ such that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \left| b_{k}\right|^2<\infty$ . Suppose $\left| a_{nk}-b_k \right| \rightarrow 0$
> as $n \rightarrow \infty$.  Show that
> $$\left| \sum_{k=1}^\infty (a_{nk}-b_k)\right| \rightarrow 0 \text{ as } n \rightarrow \infty.$$

I see that $a_n, b \in \ell^2$ and I need to show that $\left\|a_n-b \right\|_{\ell^1} \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$, but I'm not sure considering properties of $\ell^1, \ell^2$-sapces would be helpful since I don't really know what to do with the condition $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \left| a_{nk}\right|^2 < M$. And I failed to manipulate the condition to get the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not true. Let $a_{nk}=1$ if $n=k$ and $0$ otherwise. Then the hypothesis is satisfied with $M=2$ and $b_n=0$ for all $n$. But $\sum_k (a_{nk}-b_n)=1$ for all $n$.

What is true is  $\sum_k (a_{nk}c_k -b_kc_k) \to 0$ for every $(c_k) \in \ell^{2}$. To prove this use Cauchy - Schwarz inequality for $\sum\limits_{k=N+1}^{\infty} (a_{nk}-b_k)(c_k)$ . Note that the sum from $k=1$ to $k=N$ tends to $0$ for every fixed $N$.

Comment: I'm showing that for a Hilbert space with orthonormal basis $\left\{e_n\right\}_n$, $x_n \rightarrow x$ weakly  if $\left\| x_ n\right\|$ is bounded and $\langle x_n , e_k\rangle  \rightarrow \langle x, e_k \rangle$ for all $k$. Can't you deduce what I wrote if we set $x_n=\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_{nk}e_k,x=\sum_{k=1}^\infty b_{k}e_k, y=\sum_{k=1}^\infty c_{k}e_k $? For example $\left\| x_ n\right\|^2= \left|\langle x_n, x_n\rangle \right|= \left|\langle \sum_{k=1}^\infty a_{nk} e_k, \sum_{k=1}^\infty a_{nk} e_k \rangle \right| = \sum_{k=1}^\infty\left|a_{nk} \right|^2< M $.

Comment: But the conclusion part is not the same as weak convergence of $(x_n)$ to $x$. Weak convergence would mean $\sum_k (a_{nk}c_k -b_kc_k) \to 0$ for every $(c_k) \in $\ell^{2}$. @MikePosner

Comment: That's kinda what I did. If we use Cauchy - Schwarz inequality then we get $\left| \sum_{k=N+1}^\infty (a_{nk}-b_k) c_k\right|^2 \leq \left(\sum_{k=N+1}^\infty \left|a_{nk}-b_k\right|^2\right)\left(\sum_{k=N+1}^\infty \left|c_k\right|^2\right)$ and $\sum_{k=N+1}^\infty \left|c_k\right|^2$ is bounded so we only need to show $\left(\sum_{k=N+1}^\infty \left|a_{nk}-b_k\right|^2\right) \rightarrow 0$. I don't still see how to make the conclusion.

Comment: @MikePosner It is the sum of $|c_k|^{2}$ from $N+1$ to $\infty$ which tends to $0$. You only have to show the  other factor is bounded. For that use triangle inequality in $\ell^{2}$.